# Amazon EventBridge rule missing Input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

Did amazon remove the option to change the input of an event bridge rule? When creating my rule there is no option under "Additional settings" there is no "Configure target input" for my rule. When I get to the review page the input is just "Matched event" which for me is just a 15 minute schedule.

Is there any way to configure the input from the console?

Comment: I've seen a few people complain about this lately. You can definitely still configure this through the API, and anything that uses the API like CloudFormation or Terraform. My guess is they may have removed it from the UI to get you to switch over to using the new EventBridge Pipes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes.html

Comment: That is incredibly annoying as I am creating a UI specific walkthrough

Comment: Click the feedback button at the bottom of the AWS UI, and let them know how you feel about it. They won't see if you post it here.